How to build java project (Ant) with external files in Netbeans?
I am creating an application in Apache Netbeans, I want to export it to a .jar file can be run. I have a MS Access database and a text file in my project but when I build the project from Netbeans, it does not include the external files in the .jar file and the app cannot run.
I tried adding the files to the build.xml file using the following (which I got from here):
<target name="-post-jar">
    <jar destfile="dist/MyJar.jar" update="true">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}">
            <include name="Database.accdb"/>
            <include name="textfile.txt"/>
        </fileset>
    </jar>
</target>

But this did not work (when I ran the .jar file the files could not be found)
Any help would be appreciated :)

How are you accessing the files in your application? Using them as files is probably wrong.

Hi. I access the database using connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://Database.accdb");
and the textfile using Scanner scFile = new Scanner(new File("textfile.txt"));

This would be for files but anything in the JAR is not a file.

At runtime, copy the files to a folder outside your app.
